# How to prevent screen rotation with android development in delphi xe5 Firemonkey

Tags: android, delphi

I have found the following code to prevent the screen from rotating but when i compile i get a bunch of undeclared identifiers: `IFMXScreenService, TPlatformServices`.
Obviously this is because of missing units. But i cannot find what unit it is.

Code:

```
procedure TLogin.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  ScreenService: IFMXScreenService;
  OrientSet: TScreenOrientations;
begin
  if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXScreenService) then
  begin
    ScreenService := TPlatformServices.Current.GetPlatformService
      (IFMXScreenService) as IFMXScreenService;
    OrientSet := [TScreenOrientation.soLandscape];
    ScreenService.SetScreenOrientation(OrientSet);
  end;
end;
```

Any assistance would be great thank you.

Update:

The unit missing was `FMX.Platform`. But when i try to compile now, i get an error: `\\android\\debug\\libproject.so: open: permission denied`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `FMX.Platform` to your `uses` clause, and get rid of the redundant call to `GetPlatformService()`:

```
uses
  ..., FMX.Platform;

procedure TLogin.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  ScreenService: IFMXScreenService;
  OrientSet: TScreenOrientations;
begin
  if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXScreenService, IInterface(ScreenService)) then
  begin
    OrientSet := [TScreenOrientation.soLandscape];
    ScreenService.SetScreenOrientation(OrientSet);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 5):

Go to Project Options -> Application -> Orientation

Check Custom Orientation and check one of the Landscape options.

Answer (score 1):

This has changed in Delphi 10.4 and later...

```
if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXScreenService, IInterface(ScreenService)) then
begin
  OrientSet := [TScreenOrientation.soPortrait];
  ScreenService.SetSupportedScreenOrientations(OrientSet) // WAS .SetScreenOrientation(OrientSet);
end;
```